# How to remove http(s) off of a URL on the page?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am dynamically pulling in a URL from my CMS onto the page to be part of the page content, but I want to display it without the http:// (or https://) portion by using javascript.

Basically I want this:

[image]

To render on the page as:

[image]

Please see my HTML:

```
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-0e4572c elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="0e4572c" data-element_type="widget" id="partner-website-element" data-widget_type="heading.default">
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <h5 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">
      <a href="https://www.theurl.com">Visit https://www.theurl.com</a>
    </h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note I added the ID of "partner-website-element" to the first div (I can only add a class or an ID to that element).

Here is my javascript so far:

```
<script>
    var cleanurl = document.getElementById("partner-website-element").getElementsByTagName('a').innerHTML;
    cleanurl.replace(/http(s):\/\/(www)/gi, '');
</script>
```

When I load the page I get the error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

PS: I'm not sure if my regex is right yet since so far I have only tried replacing `http` with `''`, ie `cleanurl.replace(/http/gi, '');`

Comment: `console.log( cleanurl );` and you will see that `cleanurl` is not what you think it is. If you succeed then it should be multiple `<a>` tags which you need to loop.

Comment: `"https://something.com".replace("https://", "");` Or, you know, just don't type in `https://` in your anchor tag text

Comment: You need to modify your script so it waits for the page to load before attempting to reference the DOM. There are multiple ways to do this and it is platform dependent, you could use a library like jQuery to handle these discrepancies for you, or try to handroll your own solution. Edit: Actually it looks like [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) is well supported nowadays, you should probably use that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the vanilla JS for it:

```js
console.log( `https://www.theurl.com`.replace(/https?:\/\/(www\.)?/gi, '') );
console.log( `http://www.theurl.com`.replace(/https?:\/\/(www\.)?/gi, '') );
console.log( `https://theurl.com`.replace(/https?:\/\/(www\.)?/gi, '') );
```

Your `cleanurl` is failing because you are calling `.innerHTML` on an object which doesn't provide that method. You need to loop `cleanurl` and use `.innerHTML` against each member.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand but you should use `.innerText`, also if you want to use that query you should use `cleanurl[0]` the error is because  cleanurl it is not a `String` so `.replace()` does not work.

```js
var a = document.querySelector("#partner-website-element a");
var url = a.innerText;
a.innerText = url.replace(/https?:\/\/w{3}\./gi,"");
```

```html
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-0e4572c elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="0e4572c" data-element_type="widget" id="partner-website-element" data-widget_type="heading.default">
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <h5 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">
      <a href="https://www.theurl.com">Visit https://www.theurl.com</a>
    </h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Wait until the page loads before accessing the DOM
2. Access the first element of the `NodeList` returned by `getElementsByTagName`
3. Clean the url and set it back

   ```
    document.onLoad = function () {

          var ele = document.getElementById("partner-website-element").getElementsByTagName('a');

          ele[0].innerHTML = ele[0].innerHTML.replace(/http(s):\/\/(www)/gi, '');
    }
   ```

Comment: you should use ele[0].innerHTML in this case

Comment: @Emeeus Yes - it returns a NodeList. Thanks. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

## Answering My Own Question Here.

Here is my working code / what I ended up doing (welcome criticism/improvement ideas), including my own comments added:

```
<script>
  // Gets the URL of a link into the anchor text and removes extra characters.
  // Notes:
  // - This could most likely be done more elegantly since they are referencing the same element!
  // - This was done in a WP/Elementor page with weird selectors.
  var myanchor = document.querySelector(".partner-website-url.elementor-widget.elementor-widget-heading a");
  var myurl = document.querySelector(".partner-website-url.elementor-widget.elementor-widget-heading a").href;
  var cleanurl = myurl.replace(/http(s)://(www\.)/, '').replace(//+$/, '');
  myanchor.innerHTML += cleanurl;
</script>
```